# Importing data into an existing database in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using `neo4j-import` to import millions of nodes and relationship.

Is there any option to create relationships in to the existing database. I want to import the relationship using `neo4j-import` because I have millions of relationships.

Your cooperation is truly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`neo4j-import` can be solely used for initial imports.

For huge mass imports into an existing database in offline mode you can use the [batch inserter API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert.html).

If the database needs to be online while importing you can use `LOAD CSV` with periodic commit functionality.

A third option is to write an [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) to Neo4j and do the import programmatically.

Comment: [tag:StefanArmbruster] Thank you for clear explanation. And I did it using batch inserter API.